# JavaScript to CoffeeScript Error

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a function that toggles all of the others checkboxes when the last checkbox is clicked.

It works perfectly in ordinary JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#manage').click(function(event) {   
      if(this.checked) {
          $('.checkbox:checkbox').each(function() {
              this.checked = true;                        
          });
      }
      if(!this.checked) {
          $('.checkbox:checkbox').each(function() {
              this.checked = false;                        
          });
      }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PauaN/9/

However when I compile into CoffeeScript  (using http://js2coffee.org/ ) the functionality breaks when the checkboxes are toggled off:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#manage").click (event) ->
    if @checked
      $(".checkbox:checkbox").each ->
        @checked = true

    unless @checked
      $(".checkbox:checkbox").each ->
        @checked = false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FRs5d/7/

I think this is because the second each loop is only running once.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things happens:

1. Coffee Script puts return at end of every function, so 
   `@checked = true` changes into `return this.checked = true;`
2. If function in Jquery `each()` returns `false`, it does not continue.

What will solve this, is changing your last line

```
@checked = false
```

to something like this:

```
@checked = false
return true
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the following. In the converted script the implicit return created by CoffeeScript is `false`

```
unless @checked
  $(".checkbox:checkbox").each () ->
    @checked = false
    # here false is returned stopping the each function from continuing
```

so the solution is adding `true` at the end of the function

```
unless @checked
  $(".checkbox:checkbox").each () ->
    @checked = false
    true
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afrxk/4/) shows it in action.